# log4j2 cannot send error notification to email

Tags: java, xml, log4j, log4j2, smtpappender

I am currently creating an Java Application. I want to send an email notification to my gmail account when there are error occurs in my application. I have part of my log4j2.xml file below. But when I am trying to run my application, the app print out

```
2015-08-28 14:16:51,671 ERROR Unable to locate appender Email for logger
```

I am not sure why it doesn't work. Help will be appreciate

This is part of my log4j2.xml file.

```
<appender name= "Email" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">

        <param name = "BufferSize" value = "50"/>
        <param name = "SMTPHost" value = "smtp.gmail.com"/>
        <param name = "SMTPort" value = "465"/>
        <param name = "SMTPUsername" value ="myemail@gmail.com"/>
        <param name = "SMTPPassword" value ="mypassword"/>
        <param name = "From" value="myemail@gmail.com"/>
        <param name = "To" value="myemail@gmail.com"/>
        <param name = "Subject" value="Testing Log4j mail notification"/>
        <layout class = "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}]%n%n%-5p%n%n%c%n%n%m%n%n" />
        </layout>

        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="error"/>
            <param name="LevelMax" value="fatal"/>
        </filter>

    </appender>
```

This is my main class

```
package com.testcase;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger ;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;


public class log4jDemo {

    protected static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(log4jDemo.class);

    public static void main (String [] args){


    logger.trace("trace message");
    logger.warn("warn message");
    logger.error("Error message, a very long error message");

    }
}
```

Comment: is a logger declared in your `log4j2.xml` file?

Comment: Your configuration file is named 'log4j2.xml' which is meant for log4j 2.x when you are using log4j 1.x. Your config should be named "log4j.xml" instead

Comment: You are setting xml code is for Log4j 1.x (org.apache.log4j.abcccc), but you are using filename syntax (log4j2.xml) for Log4j version 2.x